# Правильность реализации одиночки

Tags: python, python-3.x

Здравствуйте!
Помогите, пожалуйста в проектировании приложения. Я программирую многопоточное приложение на Python3 (использую треды). В качестве ORM использую SQLAlchemy. В данном приложении несколько потоков подключаются к БД. Подключение к БД реализовано через одиночку. Одиночка в данной реализации представляет собой класс задекорированный следующим образом:

```
def singleton(cls):
    instance = {}

    def get_instance():
        if cls not in instance:
            instance[cls] = cls()
        return instance[cls]
    return get_instance()

@singleton
class Connector:
    def __init__(self):
        db = "параметры подключения"
        self.engine = create_engine(db)
        Session = sessionmaker(bind=self.engine)
        self.session = Session()

    def get_connection(self):    # вызывается когда нужен доступ к базе
        return self.session
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, какие могут быть проблемы в данной реализации? Не возникнут ли блокировки при попытке воспользоваться методами класса Connect в разных потоках? (По идее наложение блокировки на экземпляр класса должен производить GIL). 
На текущий момент у меня периодически в работе потоков появляется ошибка:

> sqlalchemy.exc.ResourceClosedError: This Connection is closed

Comment: «должен производить GIL» — не должен, поток (вместе с GIL) может быть переключен в любой момент, в том числе в процессе чтения результата с БД, думаю от этого и сбоит. Обычно делают по отдельному подключению на каждый поток

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Возможно, такая реализация будет работать лучше:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker, scoped_session
from contextlib import contextmanager

engine = create_engine(db, pool_size=50, max_overflow=0)

@contextmanager
def session():
    connection = engine.connect()
    db_session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(autocommit=False, autoflush=True, bind=engine))
    try:
        yield db_session
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
    finally:
        db_session.remove()
        connection.close()
```

Применение:

```
with session() as s:
    pass  # do some
```

Руководствовался [доками](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/pooling.html), похоже решение зависит от выбранной СУБД, а вообще тема интересная, было бы здорово посмотреть производительные примеры опытных участников.

Answer (score 2):

1. Нельзя использовать одну сессию из разных потоков. Каждому потоку
   своя сессия. [Здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18265238/5485944) по этому поводу очень подробно отвечено. Вот
   еще один очень показательный фрагмент документации (кроме
   приведенных в том ответе) - [Is the session thread-safe?](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_basics.html#is-the-session-thread-safe)
2. Ваш синглтон с виду решает практически ту же самую задачу, что и
   `ScopedSession`.
3. Из названия метода `get_connection` может показаться, что речь идет
   о подключении к БД. Сессия SQLAlchemy не то же самое, что простое
   подключение. Игнорирование различий этих понятий может привести к
   печальным последствиям. Например, незакрытая сессия может привести к
   потере данных.